# Azure webapp Tomcat 8 configuration

Tags: tomcat, azure, web-applications

I have switched from a tomcat 8 webapp of the azure marketplace to the new native webapp (configuration ui).

The Web app configuratiou ui now allows to setup a tomcat 7 or 8 directly (no need to use a custom webapp from the marketplace)

Using the marketplace tomcat, it was possible to setup tomcat config files (like Web.xml) using ftp because the bin directory was exposed: d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\tomcatxxxx

Now, with the configuration ui, the virtual machine which embed the tomcat does not expose the bin directory: I can see from the console that the windows server has 3 versions of tomcat in the program files directory but I have no way to edit files in this directory.

Someone knows how to change tomcat configuration for the new configuration ui?
I want to setup the java options and increase the xms and xmx settings plus change the default tomcat user session timeout.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to change the global Tomcat configuration? You ought to be able to do everything from within your own application's WAR file/directory.

Comment: Not really, JRE settings are made in catalina setting files and also adjusting default session timeout needs settings from outside the war => pure tomcat settings

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have missed the part about wanting to change heap settings. Of course, you must do that at the Tomcat level and not at the application level. I'll delete both comments in a few days because they are just noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few search, a Microsoft tech guy answered my question on Azure Forum:
[Setup Tomcat using web.config](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/#comment-2040217974)

More details on the web.config content and way to put it on the webapp directory:
[Add a Java application to Azure App Service Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/)

Basically, the tomcat application can be setup using a web.config file.
This file has to be upload on home\site\wwwroot\ by FTP or using the Kudu Azure extension (nice one).

This way works for both tomcat webapp from the marketplace AND tomcat webapp from the new configuration UI.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of web.config file, we can create a new "Tomcat" instance using "App Services".

[image]

And manage the configuration / public access url:

[image]

Default Page:

[image]